# libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with '“options'

Tags: wireless

I am trying to install wifi driver on HP laptop

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de
```

After this I this got error:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with '“options'
```

Comment: There is something incorrect in the referenced file. Please check it with: `cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf` You will probably need to make a correction. Edit your question to show the result and we'll propose an answer. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: there is "option ...someting. ."  i just remove double quotes and now it's working thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've opened the file, and removed the string that starts from "options". (The file became empty).

```
nano /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
```

It helps me.